# mui-datatables: Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [mui-datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) and I found out that it is not compatible with functional components (Material UI v4), however I figured that [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) should fix my problem, I followed it but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

```
// TablesList.js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    content: theme.styles.content,
}));

const TableList = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const columns = ["Name", "Company", "City", "State"];
    const options = {
        filterType: 'textField',
        rowsPerPage: 50,
        rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 50, 100]
    };

    const data = [
        ["Joe James", "Test Corp", "Yonkers", "NY"],
        ["John Walsh", "Test Corp", "Hartford", "CT"],
        ["Bob Herm", "Test Corp", "Tampa", "FL"],
        ["James Houston", "Test Corp", "Dallas", "TX"],
    ];
    return (
        <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar}/>
            <MUIDataTable
                ref={ref} // Passing ref
                title={"Employee List"}
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
            />
        </main>
    )
});
```

And I'm calling this component in a `Route`:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={TablesList} ref={ref}/>
```

So what am I doing wrong here? cause I still see the error in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Material UI 4 is not supported yet. There is still an open ticket on GitHub: (see https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/595